# Will I ever have any kind of problem when using "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" for IBOutlets initialization? If yes what's an example?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" is used when deserializing my object(which is created on storyboard), but is it correct to initialize `IBOutlets` in it? If not, where should do `IBOutlets` initialization?

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Read [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but is it correct to initialize IBOutlets in it

No. IBOutlets are declared Optional so they already have a value, `nil`, and do not need to be initialized in your initializer. The outlets will be hooked up later in the nib-loading process, automatically.